# How to set Brocade 200E SAN Fabric Switch Port Health Monitoring to "monitored"

Tags: storage-area-network, switch, health, fabric

I have a Brocade SAN Fabric Switch, a 200E.

When using the web based management interface "SwitchExplorer" I can click the port, and I see "Port Administration Services".

In the first screen of data that appreas, there's a row called "Health" which has value "Unmonitored".

Do you know how to set this port to be Monitored? And if also - what "Health" monitoring does?

I'm hoping it'll email or log if there's a connection or disconnection..

Many thanks for looking...

Kenny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you must buy a license for Brocade's product called "Fabric Watch" to allow port health monitoring.